# Deleting all folders and files underneath it in linux with a certain name?

Tags: linux, file-management

I have the following structure:

```
/.svn
/bla/.svn
/hello/.svn
/bla/bla/bla/.svn
... etc
```

I want to delete all the .svn folders. How do I do it?

It's NOT:

```
rm -rf .svn
```

In windows you use the /s trigger. How do you do it linux?

Answer (score 11):

Use the command find:

`find . -type d -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;`

{} is the filename, -type d means directories.

**Warning: use find and rm together with caution!**

Comment: +1 for the warning, find and rm is potentially a very dangerous combination.

Comment: Will fill your terminal with lots of warnings of "find: '.../.svn': No such file or directory". The directories get removed, but you can avoid the warnings with `-depth` (see my answer).

Answer (score 9):

```
find . -depth -type d -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Differences to other solutions already presented:

- without `-depth`, the command will attempt to recurse into the .svn directory after it has deleted it, resulting in error messages.
- without `-type d` (which limits your search to directories), you would also delete *files* of the given name. (Most likely you won't have any, but you shouldn't take chances when doing a combination of "find" and "rm".)

Comment: While your -depth addition is very good (+1 from me), I did have the -type d option in my solution.

Answer (score 5):

If your exact need is to remove `.svn` directories and not a more general solution for removing specifically named directories, you should consider using [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html):

```
$ svn export . /tmp/new-dir
```

This will create a copy of the svn work area in the current directory into a new directory at `/tmp/new-dir`. You don't need to create the new directory first. Subversion will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf {}\;
```

Should work for you.
It first finds all folders named `.svn`
Then executing `rm -rf` for each folder found.

Result:
No more .svn folders

Comment: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: That's what happens when you forget the space before `\;`.